# Blazor - Combine Client and Server

Tags: blazor

A general start-up question for using Blazor.

### WebAssembly Project (without hosting)

This seems to operate as a single page app 'hosted' in client-side Index.html, which loads "_framework/blazor.webassembly.js".

### Server Project

This seems to operate as a single page app 'hosted' in server-side _Host.cshtml, which loads "_framework/blazor.server.js".

### WebAssembly (ASP.NET Core Hosted)

I had assumed this would give me the best of both worlds where a route found on the server would execute 'hosted' in _Host.cshtml and a route found on the client would execute 'hosted' in _Index.html.

However, the templated server project does not include _Host.cshtml.

### Requirement

1. One part of the application involves managing static data which requires a persistent connection for database updates.
2. The other part of the application can operate as a client-side SPA, which downloads static data and is then resilient to loss of connection.

So, it seemed reasonable to go for the hosted WebAssembly model and get best of both worlds, but I have a feeling I'm totally misunderstanding Blazor use case.

Has anybody else been down this rabbit-hole and have any advice on best setup for these requirements?

Comment: I'm looking for the same and and this may be the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62132221/437393

Comment: As an alternative, this seemed to be achieved by overriding JS loading server and wasm components in specific order - https://itnext.io/blazor-switching-server-and-webassembly-at-runtime-d65c25fd4d8

Comment: Thanks for those.  I will take a look.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use both Blazor client and server in same web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58131674/how-to-use-both-blazor-client-and-server-in-same-web)

Comment: Thanks, Remi.  Yeah was reading up on .Net 8 this morning and saw that they'd added this.  A nice addition!